# What is the minimum discrimination error probability for $n$ equiprobable pure states?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-states

Consider $n$ equi-probable quantum states $|\phi_i\rangle$ such that $|\langle \phi_i|\phi_j\rangle| = x$ for all $i \neq j$.

I want to prove that the minimum probability of error possible when discriminating these states using an (optimal) POVM/measurements is at least some factor of $x$.

My conjecture is that the probability of error is at least $\frac{n-1}{n}(1 - \sqrt{1-x^2})$. The source of the conjecture comes from the formula for two states (See https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1970 Eqn (12), for example).

I have a strong intuition that such a factor of $x$ should exist.

Any pointer/directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have reasons to think that your conjecture is *not* correct? Have you experimented with it at all?

Comment: My thesis is only a couple of days old (I have been trying to prove something much deeper which is almost-certainly true, and this conjecture could help prove it). I have some experiment results that seem to match somewhat, but not completely (but no contradiction yet). But, yes -- trying to test it empirically in an extensive manner should be a good first step.

Comment: related on qc.SE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26972/55